# Merge 2 nested JSON objects with add or update fields in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

Here are the JSON in play:

**origJSON**

```
{
  "2014": {
    "grade": "A-",
    "className": "Geography 101"
  },
  "_id": "564d098e2e59e72412e4d795",
  "purl": "3",
  "firstName": "Jon",
  "finalGrade": "B",
  "template": "User.html",
  "sensitive": "{"ssn":\"123-00-6789\",\"acc\":\"987654300\",\"password\":\"zxcvbn!\"}"
}
```

**newJSON**

```
{
  "purl": "3",
  "firstName": "Jon",
  "sensitive": {
    "password": "qazwx",
    "phone": "1234567890"
  }
}
```

**merged origJSON**

```
{
  "2014": {
    "grade": "A-",
    "className": "Geography 101"
  },
  "_id": "564d098e2e59e72412e4d795",
  "purl": "3",
  "firstName": "Jon",
  "finalGrade": "B",
  "template": "User.html",
  "sensitive": {
    "password": "qazwx",
    "phone": "1234567890"
  }
}
```

**desired origJSON**

```
{
  "2014": {
    "grade": "A-",
    "className": "Geography 101"
  },
  "_id": "564d098e2e59e72412e4d795",
  "purl": "3",
  "firstName": "Jon",
  "finalGrade": "B",
  "template": "User.html",
  "sensitive": {
    "ssn": "123-00-6789",
    "acc": "987654300",
    "password": "qazwx",
    "phone": "1234567890"
  }
}
```

Here is the code to I've got:

```
for(var key in newJSON) origJSON[key]=newJSON[key];
```

Any help to get the nested objects updated instead of replaced ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the lodash library's **[`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)** method to achieve the desired result. Here are various examples of the available methods but the **[`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)** is the one you are after:

```
   var origJSON = {
        "2014": {
            "grade": "A-",
            "className": "Geography 101"
        },
        "_id": "564d098e2e59e72412e4d795",
        "purl": "3",
        "firstName": "Jon",
        "finalGrade": "B",
        "template": "User.html",
        "sensitive": {"ssn":"123-00-6789","acc":"987654300","password":"zxcvbn!"}
    };

    var newJSON = {
        "purl": "3",
        "firstName": "Jon",
        "sensitive": {
            "password": "qazwx",
            "phone": "1234567890"
        }
    };
```

Using **[`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign)**:

```
    var assigned = _.clone(newJSON);
    _.assign(assigned, origJSON);
    console.log("assign:", JSON.stringify(assigned, null, 4));
```

**Output**

```
assign: {
    "2014": {
        "grade": "A-",
        "className": "Geography 101"
    },
    "purl": "3",
    "firstName": "Jon",
    "sensitive": {
        "ssn": "123-00-6789",
        "acc": "987654300",
        "password": "zxcvbn!"
    },
    "_id": "564d098e2e59e72412e4d795",
    "finalGrade": "B",
    "template": "User.html"
}
```

Using **[`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)**

```
var merged = _.clone(newJSON);
_.merge(merged, origJSON);
console.log("merge:", JSON.stringify(merged, null, 4));
```

**Output**

```
merge: {
        "2014": {
            "grade": "A-",
            "className": "Geography 101"
        },
        "purl": "3",
        "firstName": "Jon",
        "sensitive": {
            "password": "zxcvbn!",
            "phone": "1234567890",
            "ssn": "123-00-6789",
            "acc": "987654300"
        },
        "_id": "564d098e2e59e72412e4d795",
        "finalGrade": "B",
        "template": "User.html"
    }
```

Using **[`_.defaults()`](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults)**

```
var defaulted = _.clone(newJSON);
_.defaults(defaulted, origJSON);
console.log("defaults:", JSON.stringify(defaulted, null, 4));
```

**Output**

```
defaults: {
    "2014": {
        "grade": "A-",
        "className": "Geography 101"
    },
    "purl": "3",
    "firstName": "Jon",
    "sensitive": {
        "password": "zxcvbn!",
        "phone": "1234567890",
        "ssn": "123-00-6789",
        "acc": "987654300"
    },
    "_id": "564d098e2e59e72412e4d795",
    "finalGrade": "B",
    "template": "User.html"
}
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var origJSON = {
 "2014": {
  "grade": "A-",
  "className": "Geography 101"
 },
 "_id": "564d098e2e59e72412e4d795",
 "purl": "3",
 "firstName": "Jon",
 "finalGrade": "B",
 "template": "User.html",
 "sensitive": {"ssn":"123-00-6789","acc":"987654300","password":"zxcvbn!"}
};

var newJSON = {
 "purl": "3",
 "firstName": "Jon",
 "sensitive": {
  "password": "qazwx",
  "phone": "1234567890"
 }
};


var assigned = _.clone(newJSON);
_.assign(assigned, origJSON);
console.log("assign:", assigned);

var merged = _.clone(newJSON);
_.merge(merged, origJSON);
console.log("merge:", merged);

var defaulted = _.clone(newJSON);
_.defaults(defaulted, origJSON);
console.log("defaults:", defaulted);

pre.innerHTML = "assign: " + JSON.stringify(assigned, null, 4) + "</br>merge: " + JSON.stringify(merged, null, 4) + "</br>defaults: "+ JSON.stringify(defaulted, null, 4);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Good options but the password remains the same from origJSON. It should change to what's in newJSON along with adding new "phone" field.

Comment: Also, it's throwing an error "ReferenceError: _ is not defined" when I try either of these in my nodejs

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options to do this with utility libraries like `lodash` and also ES6 destructuring (maybe).

But, imo, the most maintainable way and while using one of those, would be using an object factory. Assuming that the object structure will be the same all over... It's easier to wrap you head around, than libraries you don't know or complex clone/merge/dedupe algorithms. My bet is also that JS engines optimize factories better.

```
function outputFactory(input_1, input_2){
    // some conditions and/ or data handling here
    var desiredProperty = (input_1.someProperty >= input_2.someProperty) ? input_1.someProperty : input_2.someProperty;
    return {
        desiredProperty: desiredProperty
    }
}

var merged = outputFactory({someProperty:1}, {someProperty:2})
console.log(merged)
```

Hope this gives you an option.